# C3.js - stacked bar chart - can I make values to contain instead of stack each other?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I'm using C3.js library to create a stacked bar chart (my current code is in jsfiddle on the bottom). The problem is that by default the columns are... stacked. Since I need to create columns with min, average and max values, I'd like the values to rather contain each other, not stack. E.g. if I have min = 10, average = 50 and max = 100, I'd like the bar to be of the height 100, not 160. Is there any built in way to support such behavior?

My current code:

```
<div id="chart"></div>

<script>
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindTo: '#chart',
        data: {
            columns: [
                ['min', 10, 25, 15],
                ['avg', 50, 33, 51],
                ['max', 100, 75, 200]
            ],
            type: 'bar',
            groups: [
                ['min', 'avg', 'max']
            ]
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is a jsfiddle with my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/gguej6n0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, I'm adding this as another answer as it's completely different plus if I changed my original answer the comments would make no sense..

This time I'm taking advantage of err... feature (bug?) found in c3 that caused another user to unintentionally get the effect that you wanted.

[c3.js generate a stacked bar from JSON payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662572/c3-js-generate-a-stacked-bar-from-json-payload/37687492#37687492)

Basically, if you supply the data as json you can get the effect you want if you supply each datum as a separate point
e.g. doing this will overplot min and max on the same column even if they are meant to be stacked

```
        [{ "x-axis": "0",
            "min": 30
        },
        { "x-axis": "0",
            "max": 40
        }],
```

Whereas, this way will stack them:

```
        [{ "x-axis": "0",
            "min": 30,
            "max": 40
        }],
```

So what we need is a routine to turn the original column-based data into a json object where every datum is parcelled up separately:

http://jsfiddle.net/gvn3y0q6/5/

```
var data = [
                ['min', 10, 25, 15, 12],
                ['avg', 50, 33, 51, 24],
                ['max', 100, 75, 200, 76]
            ];

var json = [];
data.forEach (function (datum) {
    var series = datum[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < datum.length; i++) {
    var jdatum = {"x-axis": i-1};
    jdatum[series] = datum[i];
    json.push (jdatum);
  }
});

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: "x-axis",
        json:json,
        keys: {
           x: "x-axis",
           value: ["max", "avg", "min"]
        },
        groups: [
           ['max', 'avg', 'min']
        ],
        type: 'bar',
    },
     bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.95
        }
     },
     axis: {
       x: {
         padding: {
           left: 0.5,
           right: 0.5,
         }
       }
     },
     tooltip: {
         grouped: true,
         contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
             var data = this.api.data.shown().map (function(series) {
                var matchArr = series.values.filter (function (datum) {
                    return datum.value != undefined && datum.x === d[0].x;
                });
                matchArr[0].name = series.id;
                return matchArr[0];
             });

            return this.getTooltipContent(data, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color);
      }
     }
    });
```

This time, hiding a series doesn't affect the other series. There's still some tooltip jiggery-pokery needed though otherwise we only get one of the values reported in the tooltip when hovering over one of the 'stacks'. It looks like the data includes a lot of empty value points, which leads me to think this is  a bug of some sort I'm taking advantage of here..

So bearing in mind this might get fixed at some point in the future (or maybe left in, if someone points out it's useful for doing this sort of plot) - then this seems to do what you want

Comment: Thanks, it seems it's almost the right workaround - you've got a +1 for all your efforts so far :-) Unfortunately, the solution is still not ideal - it starts to bug when at least one of values equals 0. Moreover, since the stacked bars are now separate data points, hovering bars causes a strange visual effect - e.g. when min bar is hovered, max bar fades out. I'm trying to find a solution for that as well, but it seems pretty hard to find a working solution, when it's not provided by the library itself... and I'm a bit worried that using a potential bug as a solution might be risky.

Comment: Fixed the value equalling zero bug. Just lazy coding by me. i should have tested `datum.value != undefined` as just `datum.value` was barring zero values. But you're right on the other points, the opacity on hovering is wonky and relying on something that looks like a bug sets the alarms off a bit :-). I guess there you could freeze the version of c3.js, or add a feature request to the c3 github page, it doesn't look like it's getting updated a lot at the moment anyways.

Comment: Oh, I am used to writing conditions like `if(value)` as well so I didn't notice it was such a simple fix :-) So now the solution generally works and I can accept it as an answer. I'll try to solve the problem with fading by myself. Again, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything built-in that will make the bars merge into one another as you describe, but could a side-by-side view help? If so, remove the grouping.

See https://jsfiddle.net/gguej6n0/1/

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindTo: '#chart',
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['min', 10, 25, 15],
            ['avg', 50, 33, 51],
            ['max', 100, 75, 200]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    },
    bar: {
            width: {
                ratio: 0.3
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Because of the amount of x ticks that might be less (or even not) readable. That's why I needed the grouping.

Comment: Could it work in combination with [draggable/horizontal scrolling](http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-selection-draggable)? This is what I've done in one of our projects to get around the issue of too many x ticks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this option won't work as well. As a current workaround I substituted bar chart with area chart and I think I'll stick to this solution.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to implement your original question after work, and if I find a sane solution to it, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: I'll be grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think c3 has an 'overplot' bars option, but you could massage your data...

Basically process the data beforehand so max is actually max - avg, and avg is actually avg  - min

Then the tooltip routine restores the correct totals for showing to a user

Just be careful if you pass the data onto anything else and remember the data has been changed and restore it (or keep a copy)

https://jsfiddle.net/gguej6n0/5/

```
var data = [
            ['min', 10, 25, 15],
            ['avg', 50, 33, 51],
            ['max', 100, 75, 200]
        ];

    for (var n = data.length-1; n > 0; n--) {
    for (var m = 1; m < data[n].length; m++) {
    data[n][m] -= data[n-1][m];
  }
}


var chart = c3.generate({
      bindTo: '#chart',
    data: {
        columns: data,
        type: 'bar',
        groups: [
            ['min', 'avg', 'max']
        ]
    },
    tooltip: {
      contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
                var dc = d.map (function (dd) {
                    return {value: dd.value, x: dd.x, id: dd.id, name: dd.name, index: dd.index};
            })
                for (var n= 1; n < dc.length; n++) {
                    dc[n].value += dc[n-1].value;
            }
            return this.getTooltipContent(dc, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color);
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice workaround. This seems to fix the problem, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, after a bit of testing it seems that this method fails when we hide one of the lower series. It seems that data should be recalculated on each hide event and should be based on which series are shown.

Comment: ahh, grrr. I thought this could be fixed by using the .onrendered callback but it's too late by then, the graph has rendered. I have another idea though...